# Gorm selecting data 1 column to some struct attribute

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to select data using gorm with struct object like this:

```
type Song struct {
   Title string `json:"title" gorm:"column:title"`
   Artist string `json:"artis" gorm:"column:artist"`
   Producer string json:"producer" gorm:"column:artist"
}
```

With database data just have 2 column title, and artist. You can see I want to set the data from column artist to multiple struct attribute (Artist and Producer).

I was try to use normal select. The artist attribute is filled with the data, but the producer will be blank.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

See doc [gorm-hooks](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Querying-an-object).

Like this:

```
func (u *Song ) AfterFind(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  u.Producer = u.Artist 
  return
}
```

And `Producer` field shouldn't has `gorm:"column:artist"` tag. It may cause some other problems. If database doesn't have this field, suggests use `gorm:"-"`.

Or

```
type Song struct {
   Title string `json:"title" gorm:"column:title"`
   // Use Producer in code, but artist in database.
   Producer string `json:"producer" gorm:"column:artist"`
}
```